# Retrieve arguments and attributes of a queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

In the REST API of the RabbitMQ you can get various information of an existing queue (http://rabbit.example.com:15672/api/queues/):

```
{
    "memory": 10888,
    "messages": 0,
    "messages_details": {
        "rate": 0
    },
    "messages_ready": 0,
    "messages_ready_details": {
        "rate": 0
    },
    "messages_unacknowledged": 0,
    "messages_unacknowledged_details": {
        "rate": 0
    },
    "idle_since": "2014-12-12 13:59:46",
    "policy": "",
    "exclusive_consumer_tag": "",
    "consumers": 0,
    "backing_queue_status": {
        "q1": 0,
        "q2": 0,
        "delta": [
            "delta",
            "undefined",
            0,
            "undefined"
        ],
        "q3": 0,
        "q4": 0,
        "len": 0,
        "pending_acks": 0,
        "target_ram_count": "infinity",
        "ram_msg_count": 0,
        "ram_ack_count": 0,
        "next_seq_id": 0,
        "persistent_count": 0,
        "avg_ingress_rate": 0,
        "avg_egress_rate": 0,
        "avg_ack_ingress_rate": 0,
        "avg_ack_egress_rate": 0
    },
    "status": "running",
    "name": "${sistemaConsumidor}.${domain}.${evento}.RetryQueue",
    "vhost": "/",
    "durable": true,
    "auto_delete": true,
    "arguments": {
        "x-dead-letter-exchange": "${exchangeType}.${domain}",
        "x-message-ttl": 5000,
        "x-dead-letter-routing-key": "${sistemaProdutor}.to.${sistemaConsumidor}.${domain}.${evento}"
    },
    "node": "rabbit@CI-41644-7"
}
```

But with the Spring-AMQP or RabbitMQ-client for Java, it seems impossible.

For example, something like this:

```
rabbitAdmin.getQueueInformation ("queueName")
```

or

```
channel.queueInformation ("queueName")
```

Comment: Well if RabbitMQ has a Rest interface you could just get the data with a good old http request yourself.

Comment: All the support system that we built in the company is using the spring-AMQP.

Answer (score 1):

Spring-AMQP and the rabbit client are for the runtime AMQP protocol; you can use Spring's `RestTemplate` to access the ReST API; it has built-in jackson support to convert the JSON.

At a higher level, you can use Spring Integration's [http:outbound-gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-outbound).